# Include batch file when creating a standalone executable from a python script (py2exe)

Tags: python, batch-file, executable, py2exe

I've been using py2exe to create executables from python scripts. I have one script now that uses a .bat file, and I'm struggling to create a standalone executable for it that can run without the .bat file in the same directory (or anywhere on the computer for that matter).

My setup.py that I'm trying basically looks like this:

```
import py2exe
from distutils.core import setup

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

from glob import glob
setup(
data_files=["",glob(r"<path to file>\myfile.bat"))],
options = {'py2exe':{bundle_files':1,'compressed':True}},
windows=[{'script': "myscript.py"}],
zipfile = None,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that batch file. Everything(?) that can be done with batch file can be done with python (built-in or external) libraries.

---

[open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) is a useful built-in python method. You can open, read, write and append to files.

Example:

```
# prints out contents of some_file.ext
with open("some_file.ext") as f:
    data = f.read()
    print data
```

---

[os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#module-os) is a powerful built-in python library. With it you can manipulate paths, create or destroy files or directories, get info on files, and more.

---

You can even use [os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) method of `os` module to execute a command as if you were executing it in a native shell.

Example:

```
os.system("echo Hi && pause")
```

---

I've done my best to try and answer your question, I'm not really experienced in programming, but I hope this helped.